# Enforce a page count that is divisible by four

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Many of the PDF documents we create with `Apache FOP`/`XSL:FO` are printed and stapled. Therefore we need a page count which is divisible by four. Unfortunately [`force-page-count`](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/force-page-count) does not seem to help here. I want to automatically insert blank pages before the last page to get a page count, which is divisible by four. Currently I need to do this manually with Adobe Acrobat afterwards. Could you please help me here?

Comment: There may be a command-line PDF utility that you could use. If you were using Antenna House Formatter, you could just use `force-page-count="doubly-even-document"` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.force-page-count).

Comment: Thank you, @TonyGraham. This is indeed a USP for Antenna.